# How to distinguish fields and subforms in jinja2?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I programmed a `Flask` application with a form using `flask_wtf`. My form contains fields and subforms. My goal is to render all fields with a loop and to treat the subforms on their own. Is it possible to distinguish between fields and subforms (with a if statement in the jinja2 template)?

**form.py**

```py
from flask_wtf import form, FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, FieldList, FormField


class MySubform(Form):
    field1 = StringField(label="field1")


class MyForm(Flaskform):
    name = StringField(label="Name")
    subform = FieldList(FormField(MySubform), min_entries=1)
```

**index.html**

```html
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ field.label(class_='col-sm-3 control-label') }}
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {{ field(class_='form-control') }}
            </div>
        </div>        
    {% endfor %}        
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.html**

```html
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.type == 'FieldList' %}
        // Process Subfields
    {% else %}
        // Process everything except FieldList's
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The type to be checked is `FormField` otherwise, the code works.